# What is the difference between Civilization V: Game of the Year Edition and Civilization V: Gold Edition

Tags: civilization-5

As the title states, what are the biggest differences between the two versions of the game? I'm really considering purchasing this game however I'm not sure which of the two versions of the game is better.

Is there a huge amount of difference in the amount of content between the two versions? I'm not exactly sure how the DLC works for this game since this will be my first strategy game in years.

EDIT: Looks like Gold edition offers a bit more. With the Gold version of the game will any future DLC be given for free to users who have already purchased the gold version (similar to how premium works for Battlefield 3 for those who've played)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_V#Release):

> A Game of the Year edition was released on September 27, 2011. It
>   includes all four of the "Cradle of Civilization" map packs, the
>   "Explorers Map Pack", as well as most of the new civilizations
>   (Babylon, Spain, Inca, Polynesia, Mongolia, and Denmark), their
>   respective scenarios, and the official digital soundtrack. However,
>   "Civilization and Scenario Pack: Korea" and "Wonders of the Ancient
>   World Scenario Pack" are not included.[47]
>
> A Gold edition was released on February 12, 2013. It includes all
>   "Cradle of Civilization" map packs, the "Explorers Map Pack", **the
>   "Wonders of the Ancient World Scenario Pack", all the DLC
>   civilizations and the Gods and Kings expansion pack.**[48]

So the Gold edition contains all of the GOTY content, plus the Korea and Ancient Wonders DLC packs and the first expansion *[Gods & Kings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_V:_Gods_&_Kings)*. **G&K is the most significant difference** between the two editions because it's a full expansion that adds a lot of new mechanics and content to the base game: religions, espionage, new techs, improved combat and diplomacy, plus several more civs and city-states.

Most of the DLC packs on the other hand are extra maps and civs that just give you new options to choose from, but as someone pointed out they are often required to join online games. They are not strictly necessary, especially for single player, but they do offer more variety.

*I disagree with the other answer's conclusion; G&K is a massive upgrade that is well worth buying Gold over GOTY.*

To address your edit, Gold edition does not include future DLC: there is now a second (and very significant) expansion *[Brave New World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_V:_Brave_New_World)* which is not included in either of these editions. To get the full package you would need to have Gold + BNW, or at least Civ5 + G&K + BNW.

**Update:** The *Complete* edition has since been released, containing "both expansions and all the DLC packs."

Answer (score 2):

The major differences are that Civilization V: Gold edition includes the *Wonders of the Ancient World Scenario Pack*, the *Gods & Kings* Expansion Pack, and the *Civilization and Scenario Pack: Korea*.  Civilization V: Game of the Year edition does not.

Below is a comprehensive list of everything included in Civilization V: Gold edition;

[image]

By getting the Game of the Year edition you're not missing anything that is required to play the game. The content that you are missing mainly comprises of additional maps, a few more scenarios, and civilizations.

*IMHO*, the game is immerse and lengthy enough to be content with GOTY edition.  If you ever wanted those missing expansions, you can always purchase the Gold Upgrade from Steam or the expansion packs later.

Comment: Exactly how much more content is that though? Like is there enough extra content to where I'd be missing out on a lot if I didn't get the Gold version?

Comment: You are not missing anything that is required to play the game, just more maps, a few more scenarios, and civilizations.

Comment: *Depending on your game play settings*, you could get anywhere between 40-80+ hours of extra play.  See edit listed above.

Comment: @Julian If you intend to play multiplayer, you should purchase the gold edition. Many multiplayer games are hosted with all DLC enabled, and if you don't have it you will not be able to join them.

Comment: @ZeroStack You glossed over the significance of G&K as an expansion pack. It is by far the most important feature of Gold edition in terms of gameplay impact.